# Using re for equality

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Is it possible to use regular expressions for equality.
How can I make this code:

```
import re
re.match(pattern, string)
```

Return `True` the same was as this code would:

```
pattern == string
```

Comment: Why would you not just use `==` ?

Comment: Try ```bool(re.match(pattern, string))```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the pattern begins with `^`, ends with `$`, and contains no special RE operators (or they're escaped), it will perform an equality test.  E.g.

```
re.match(r'^abc$', string)
re.match(r'^foo\|bar$', string)
```

can be used like

```
string == 'abc'
string == 'foo|bar'
```